# Erro ao acessar propriedade com a funcão map

Tags: javascript, react, jsx

Quando tento acessar as propriedade **this.props.arrayMenu** me exibe o seguinte erro:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined**.

conforme imagens abaixo:
[image: loop erro]
[image: dados]

```js
import React , { Component } from 'react';

export default class Categorais extends Component
{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="row">
                {                      
                    this.props.arrayMenu.map(function(menuItem, i) {
                    if (menuItem.submenu !== undefined) {
                        return (
                            <ul key={i}>{menuItem.categoria}    
                                {menuItem.submenu.map(function(subMenu, i) {                                   
                                    return <li key={i}>{subMenu.categoria}</li>;
                                })}
                            </ul>
                        )
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return (
                             <ul key={i}>
                                 <li key={i}>{menuItem.menu.categoria}</li>
                             </ul>
                        )
                    }        
                })
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Não há como saber se os "categoria" dos `menuItem` de seu `this.props.arrayMenu` são undefined ou não. Você deve verificar o conteúdo dos seus props. Não temos como adivinhar o que você desenvolve e não mostra.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayMenu` está recebendo todos dados da sua API, inclusive os objetos `menu` e `submenu`, ao fazer o map você atribui para o `jsonMenu` o `menuItem.menu`, isso para todos itens da sua lista.

Só que, ao vir um `subMenu`, você atribui ao `jsonMenu` o valor `menuItem.menu`, mas no caso do `subMenu`, isso não existe, então é `undefined`

Você teria que fazer um `if` para verificar se existe a propriedade `menu` antes de atribuí-la ao `jsonMenu`, exemplo:

```js
let jsonMenu = {};

if(menuItem.menu) {
  jsonMenu = menuItem.menu;
}
```

Nesse caso, você sempre garante que haverá o menu antes de atribuí-lo a variável.